# Error con link_to method delete en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No sé por qué ocurre esto pero desde hace unas horas que estoy batallando con este problema que de verdad no sé como solucionar.

Acá esta mi link_to:

```
<%= link_to "sign_out",sign_out_path, method: :delete %>
```

Mi ruta:

```
delete 'sign_out' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

Mi método en el controlador:

```
 def destroy
  session[:omniauth] = nil
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_path
 end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap
//= require owl.carousel.min
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.slick
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

También obtengo este error por parte de application.js:

```
Uncaught Error: ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: punc ()) (line: 11813, col: 10, pos: 494768)
Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:10623)
at js_error (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:10842)
at croak (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:19067)
at token_error (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:19204)
at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:19292)
at /tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:20761
at /tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:19938
at block_ (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:24557)
at ctor.body (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:24191)
at function_ (/tmp/execjs20160226-19-14k25i3js:2357:24256)
(in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

Y el error dice que la página no existe.

Comment: El hecho de que tengas un error de JS podria llevar a pensar que tu problema está en el js y no en el método ruby de tu controlador. Lo primero que tienes que conseguir es que el error de js desaparezca. Comprueba que tus librerías no tienen errores e incluso prueba a quitarlas mientras solucionas el problema.

Comment: lo hice, el error viene de //= require_tree . 
pero al quitarlo de todas maneras no funciona, de todas maneras revisaré el problema.. lo malo que es como buscar una aguja en un pajar de tantos js que tengo en el proyecto

Comment: La traza parece indicar que hay un error de sintaxis en algún javascript, concretamente un paréntesis cerrado ")" en algún sitio que no debería estar.

Comment: ya no me da el error, borre aquellos js que no utilizaba y parece que ahí radicaba el error pero sigue sin funcionar el delete..

Comment: Cuales son los errores que salen ahora que no tienes problemas en tu js? Puedes poner tu archivo `routes.rb`?

Comment: ninguno, los solucione.
El archivo es muy grande por eso puse como trabajo esa ruta exacta y busque en el archivo si la ruta estaba repetida o algo parecido.
hasta ahora lo hice funcionar con get pero no es la idea

Answer (score 1):

El error fue unas librerias javascript que ya no eran utilizadas en el proyecto, así que deje de pedir todas las librerías en assets/javascript
eliminando la siguiente linea de Application.js:

```
//= require_tree .
```